# $R$ is finitely generated?

Tags: modules, ideals, semi-simple-rings

I have seen many books using the idea that a commutative **semi-simple** ring with unity is finitely generated as an $R-$module but I do not understand why this is correct. Any elaboration will be appreciated!

My definition for a semi-simple ring is that it is a direct sum of simple ideals.

**My intuition:**

$R = (1)$ i.e., $R$ s finitely generated as an ideal by the element $1.$ and every ideal is an $R-$submodule and hence $R-$module. But by this intuition every ring with unity is finitely generated, no need for the word semi-simple.

Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume there is a decomposition $R = R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus R_n \oplus \cdots$ of $R$ into simple $R$-modules. We can then take any $a\in R$ and write it as $a = \sum_i a_i$ (only finitely many non-zero terms), where $a_i \in R_i$. If $i\neq j$ and $r\in R_i, s\in R_j$, then $rs = 0$ (I'll leave checking that to you as an exercise). In particular, we may write $1$ as such a sum, so assume there are infinitely many simple summands. Then (reindexing if necessary) $1 = 1_1 + 1_2 + \cdots + 1_n$. Let then $0 \neq r \in R_{n+1}$ be arbitrary. We will then have $0 \neq r = 1r (1_1 + \cdots + 1_n)r = 1_1r + \cdots + 1_nr = 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 = 0$, since there is no component of $1$ in $R_{n+1}$. The assumption that $R$ has infinitely many summands is therefore false, and so it must be a finite sum of simple modules. Every simple module is generated by a single element, so we obtain finite generation that way.

Sorry to say this, but your intuition didn't help in this situation.

Comment: Well, it is also true that every unital ring is generated by a single element over itself, so it's understandable why OP was confused. They just misunderstood what their books were trying to say, and you provided the proof of the correct statement.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yep. That is most likely the case. Or maybe the OP just worded the idea in a strange way.

Comment: Why $a$ can be written as finitely many nonzero terms?

Comment: So you @diracdeltafunk are saying that every unital ring is finitely generated as an $R-$module? where the generating set is $(1)$ ?

Comment: @NelliKuukeri so can we say that any semi-simple ring is finitely generated?

Comment: Correct -- every unital ring is generated by $\{1\}$. @Nelli is pointing out that you've misinterpreted the books you were reading -- they were not just saying that every semisimple ring is finitely generated, because that is trivial! Instead, the interesting claim is that every semisimple ring is a *finite* direct sum of simple left ideals.

Comment: Why every semisimple ring is finitely generated as an $R-$module? is it because it is finitely generated by $1$? .... is it for the same reason as the unital ring?@diracdeltafunk

Comment: why $rs = 0$? is it because of the direct sum we have which means that the intersection is zero? So, you omiited writing the intersection sign?@NelliKuukeri

Comment: @diracdeltafunk If you have any answers to my questions to Nelli I would appreciate reading yours also!

Comment: @MathFear In situations like this, where you're confused about what a book is saying precisely, you can help yourself out tremendously by backtracking and reading the relevant definitions. For example, semisimple rings are always assumed unital -- probably all rings are unital in the books you're reading!

Comment: What about my question about $a$ and why it can be written as finitely many non-zero terms?@diracdeltafunk